# Connecting to Oracle from ASP.NET is very slow - how to diagnose?

Tags: asp.net, performance, oracle, debugging

I have an ASP.NET application that's connecting to an oracle database.

Performance on some queries in dev is very slow - on the order of 90 seconds to connect to the database, run a a query (actually, call a SP in a package) and return a single row of results.

I've run a profiler on the app, and just about 100% of the time is spent in native code, Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsDac.Read (in OraOps10.dll )

The same query runs fine in prod.  TNSPING the dev db is under 10ms, and in fact I have no problem connecting via sqldeveloper.

How can I determine what's causing the slowdown?

Answer (score 1):

Are the DEV web server and DB on the same machine? Is it your local machine?

If not, are the response times similar to your local machine?

Can you point the DEV web application to PROD? If so is the timing the same?

Is this a single query, or all queries?